# Convert GMT timestamp (DD/MM/YYYY) to local time (MM/DD/YYYY) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The timestamp I get from a server's SOAP response is formatted in European Notation and in GMT time (ex: 08/07/2010 11:22:00 AM). I want to convert it to local time and change the formatting to (MM/DD/2010 HH:MM:SS AM/PM).

I know about the JavaScript Date object but can't figure out the logic of how to do the conversion. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var serverTimestamp = storArray[a][0];
var pieces = serverTimestamp.split('/'); 
storArray[a][0] = pieces[1] + '/' + pieces[0] + '/' + pieces[2];
var gmt = new Date(storArray[a][0]);
var localTime = gmt.getTime() - (gmt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000); // convert gmt date to minutes
var localDate = new Date(localTime); // convert it into a date
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. the storArray variable is the place in the array where the timestamp is

Comment: Why don't you just append the timezoen and convert the string?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need date objects for this? If all you're doing is switching the first two parts of a string of that exact format,

```
var pieces = str.split('/');
str = pieces[1] + '/' + pieces[0] + '/' + pieces[2];
```

Comment: This worked great for switching the formatting, but I also need to adjust the time from GMT to local.

Answer (score 1):

Parse dates using:

```
Date.parse("08/07/2010 11:22:00 AM");
```

To convert the GMT date to local date (one on the browser or js useragent) use the following function:

```
     function getLocalTime(gmt)  {
       var min = gmt.getTime() / 1000 / 60; // convert gmt date to minutes
       var localNow = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); // get the timezone 
                                                      // offset in minutes            
       var localTime = min - localNow; // get the local time
       return new Date(localTime * 1000 * 60); // convert it into a date
    }

    var dt = new Date(Date.parse("08/07/2010 11:22:00 AM"));
    var localDate = getLocalTime(dt);
```

Next is date formatting, which is quite simple. Call the following functions on your newly obtained (local) date:

```
localDate.getXXX(); // where XXX is Hour, Minutes, etc.
```

Note: Tested in FF. Tweak as required in other browsers :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year old and has an accepted answer. Just in case someone comes around looking...

You can append the timezone information to the formatted string and create a date object to get what you want.

```
var x = "08/07/2010 11:22:00 AM".split('/');
var d = new Date(x[1] + '/' + x[0] + '/' + x[2] + " GMT");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u39nn/)

Just to make sure I understand what you wanted, I ran the accpeted answer along with this, both return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
function switchFormat(dateString) {
    var a = dateString.split('/'),
        b;
    b = a[0];
    a[0] = a[1];
    a[1] = b;
    return a.join('/');
}
```

**Edited**

[Try it here](http://jsbin.com/asana3/edit)

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 you are getting date from input type date like below

[image]

like  2021-08-18    as string

then

var formatted date = date.split('-')[2]+"/"+date.split('-')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZPn9.png)+"/"+date.split('-')[0])

result will be    18/08/2021